# Laravel validation with at least two fields required

Tags: laravel-5

Lets say I have three input fields such as a,b and c.

How to write a validation rules so that when a user submits the form, at least two of the fields are filled.

This is my current rule, but it checks only if one of the field is filled.

```
[
    'a' => 'required_without_all:b,c',
    'b' => 'required_without_all:a,c',
    'c' => 'required_without_all:a,b',
]
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the [Laravel 5 documentation on validation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/validation),

> **required_without_all:foo,bar,...**
>
> The field under validation must be present *only when* all of the other
>   specified fields are not present.

But in your case, you want that at least 2 fields are filled. So for that, you need, `required_with`

> **required_with:foo,bar,...**
>
> The field under validation must be present *only if* any of the other
>   specified fields are present.

So, change the rules to this:

```
[
    'a' => 'required_with:b,c'
    'b' => 'required_with:a,c'
    'c' => 'required_with:a,b'
]
```

Hope this helps you out.